# SQL loader issue in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am getting the below error while trying to load data via sql loader, can someone help to resolve this issue.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Raghu>sqlldr hr/hrschema control=D:\sql\1.csv
SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Sep 29 09:03:41 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (D:\sql\1.csv)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Users\Raghu>
```

ctl file:

```
load data infile 'd:\sql\1.csv'
TRUNCATE
into table students
fields terminated by "|"
(SID,CNAME)
```

Data file:

```
SID|CNAME
10|Java
20|UNIX
30|SQL
40|PLSQL
50|AI
60|PEGA
70|RPA
80|C
90|C++
100|Python
```

Comment: You are giving your csv file as value in the control file parameter. Create control file reffering to your data file and other parameters and try to execute sqlloader with the control file. And also execute sqllqr from the same pathe where control file resides(same location) . For more info refer [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/sql-loader-enhancements-12cr1)

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to open file (D:\sql\1.csv) SQLLoader-553: file not found SQL*Loader-509: System error: The system cannot find the file specified.

It is quite straightforward; there's no file named `1.csv` in directory  `d:\sql`. Make sure it exists and you have privileges to access it.

---

Apart from that, it (mostly) looks OK and loads data. Here's how:

```
SQL> create table students (sid number, cname varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test10.ctl log=test10.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Ned Ruj 29 10:46:51 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 10
Commit point reached - logical record count 11

SQL> select * From students;

       SID CNAME
---------- --------------------
        10 Java
        20 UNIX
        30 SQL
        40 PLSQL
        50 AI
        60 PEGA
        70 RPA
        80 C
        90 C++
       100 Python

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

"Mostly" is related to log file which contains the following line:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table STUDENTS, column SID.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

It is related to the first line in the CSV file - it contains column headers, and `SID` is not a number. It is easily handled by adding - as the first line in the control file

```
options (skip=1)
```